# How could i get pts number(/dev/pts/[X]) for virtio-serial with libvirt??

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, libvirt

Now i'm QEMU+KVM VM service with libvirt.

My VM console's serial option is like below.

```
<devices>
  <console type='pty'>
    <target type='serial' port='0'/>
  </console>
  <console type='pty'>
    <target type='virtio' port='1'/>
  </console>
</devices>
```

Because I'm not specify pts number (ex ), pty number is allocated randomly depends on host status. I can get serial0's pty number with "virsh ttyconsole" command easily. but where can i get virtio1's pty number ??

I want to use virtio-serial's pty number allocated by libvirt. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `/dev/pts/XXX`  path will be recorded in the XML document when the guest is running. The `virsh ttyconsole` command merely reads it from the XML.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Do you mean that XML document is showed with "virsh dumpxml" command?? I already try it. but there is no pts number info.

Comment: The PTS number will only be visible when the guest is actually running. If it is still in shutoff state, the XML won't show the number. This is because the actual PTS number is allocated dynamically each time.